# Is there a way to control vertical spacing between minipage elements?

Tags: spacing, pdftex, vertical-alignment, minipage

I have a large (7-chapter) document on linear algebra. In a part of the document where I do row/column operations, I have put the matrices in a figure within a minipage. I am getting a lot of vertical space between one set of "matrix-row-operation" and the next "matrix-row-operation". I am wondering if it is possible to control the vertical space.
I post below my MWE as two separate documents (a preamble and a chapter). My apologies for including, in the preamble, packages which may not be relevant.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{enumerate,mdwlist}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=12mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{float}
\setlength{\headheight}{10.0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{50.99991pt}

\usepackage{mathtools}  % for 'bmatrix*' environment
\usepackage{paralist}   % for 'inparaenum' environment\newcommand{\dist}{\displaystyle}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,exercise} %[fleqn]
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
 \array{#1}}
 \makeatother
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\spx}[1]{%
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax

 \expandafter\@gobble
\else
\expandafter\@firstofone
\fi
  {^{#1}}%{^{#1}}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\tpd[3][]{\tfrac{\partial\spx{#1}#2}{\partial#3\spx{#1}}}
\newcommand\dpd[3][]{\dfrac{\partial\spx{#1}#2}{\partial#3\spx{#1}}}

\newcommand{\md}[6]{\frac{\partial\spx{#2}#1}{\partial#3\spx{#4}\partial#5\spx{#6}}}
\newcommand{\tmd}[6]{\tfrac{\partial\spx{#2}#1}{\partial#3\spx{#4}\partial#5\spx{#6}}}
\newcommand{\dmd}[6]{\dfrac{\partial\spx{#2}#1}{\partial#3\spx{#4}\partial#5\spx{#6}}}
\newcommand{\od}[3][]{\frac{\dif\spx{#1}#2}{\dif#3\spx{#1}}}

\newcommand{\tod}[3][]{\tfrac{\dif\spx{#1}#2}{\dif#3\spx{#1}}}
\newcommand{\dod}[3][]{\dfrac{\dif\spx{#1}#2}{\dif#3\spx{#1}}}

\numberwithin{Answer}{chapter}
\numberwithin{Exercise}{chapter}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[theorem]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname] {\par\pushQED{\qed}\normalfont
\topsep6
\p@\@plus6\p@\relax\trivlist\item[\hskip\labelsep\bfseries#1\@addpunct{.}]
\ignorespaces}{\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xifthen, xparse}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newcommand\rowop[1]{\scriptstyle\smash{\xrightarrow[\vphantom{#1}]
{\mkern-4mu#1\mkern-4mu}}}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\converttorows
{>{\SplitList{,}}m}%
{\ProcessList{#1}{\converttorow}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\converttorow}{m}
{\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}{\rowop{#1}}\\}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\rowops{m}
{\;
\begin{matrix}
\converttorows {#1}
\end{matrix}
\; }
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\scshape,postheadspace=\newline]{mystyle}
\declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\scshape,postheadspace=\newline]{mystyle}

\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{sansmathaccent}
\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}
\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\scriptsize\color{blue}{$\circ$}} 
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\scriptsize\color{blue}{$\circ$}} 

\usepackage{graphicx}%,showframe}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[dutch,english]{babel}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
 \vskip\abovecaptionskip
\sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
\ifdim\wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
\ifdim\wd\@tempboxa >\hsize

 #1: #2\par
\else
\global\@minipagefalse
\hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
\fi
\vskip\belowcaptionskip}
 %%% end of multiline caption definitions
\newcommand*{\authorimg}[1]{%
\raisebox{-.3\baselineskip}{%
\includegraphics[
scale=0.80,
keepaspectratio,
 ]{#1}%
}%
}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\color{blue}}

{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{12pt}{\Huge}{\chaptertitlename\ 
\thechapter}{12pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{brown}}
{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\sffamily\large\bfseries\color{cyan}}
{\normalfont\sffamily\large\bfseries\color{cyan}}

{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\sffamily\large\bfseries\color{purple}}
{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, decorations.pathreplacing, matrix, angles, quotes, arrows, arrows.meta, datavisualization}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2.5cm, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2.5cm, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\pgfplotsset{width=5cm,compat=1.12}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
```

%#################

```
\begin{document}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block] 
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{blue}}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}
{1em}{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{rowsops}\label{ch1}
\input{Chapters/rowsops}
\end{document}

%
```

How do we find P?\
Answer:\
Reduce $(A_{3x4}|I_3)$ to row canonical form by elementary row operations

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{pmatrix}[cccc|ccc]
  2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 2 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
2 & 9 & 4 & -5 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
$\rowops {,R_1\rightarrow R_1-2r_2,R_3\rightarrow R_3-2R_2}$
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}[cccc|ccc]
0 & -5 & -2 & 3 & 1 & -2 & 0\\
1 & 2 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 5 & 2 & -3 & 0 & -2 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}[cccc|ccc]
0 & -5 & -2 & 3 & 1 & -2 & 0\\
1 & 2 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 5 & 2 & -3 & 0 & -2 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
$\rowops {,R_3\rightarrow R_3-R_1,R_1\rightarrow\frac{1}{5}R_1}$
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}[cccc|ccc]
0 & 1 &\frac{2}{5} & -\frac{3}{5} & -\frac{1}{5} &\frac{2}{5} & 0\\
1 & 2 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\1 & 2 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -4 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.36\textwidth}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}[cccc|ccc]
0 & 1 &\frac{2}{5} & -\frac{3}{5} & -\frac{1}{5} &\frac{2}{5} & 0\\
1 & 2 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -4 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{equation*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.36\textwidth}
\hspace{2ex}$\rowops {,R_2\leftrightarrow R_1,R_1\rightarrow R_1-2R_2}$
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.36\textwidth}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}[cccc|ccc]
1 & 0 &\frac{1}{5} & -\frac{1}{5} & -\frac{2}{5} &\frac{1}{5} & 0\\
0 & 1 &\frac{2}{5} & -\frac{3}{5} & -\frac{1}{5} &\frac{2}{5} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -4 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\medskip
```

Hence

```
$P=\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
-\frac{2}{5} &\frac{1}{5} & 0\\
-\frac{1}{5} &\frac{2}{5} & 0\\
1 & -4 & 1
\end{pmatrix*}$\\
```

and

```
$PA=\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
1 & 0 &\frac{2}{5} &\frac{1}{5}\\
0 & 1 &\frac{2}{5} & -\frac{3}{5}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix*}$\\
```

Comment: Can you put your code together into one block? Also, you can see if the packages are needed in the example by commenting them and seeing if the problem is still reproduced. If so, you can take them out.

Comment: Vertical spacing for equations is controlled by \abovedisplayskip, \belowdisplayskip, \shortabovedisplayskip and \shortbelowdisplayskip.

Comment: thanks @ John Kormylo but where does the \abovedisplayskip, ... go? after \begin{equation} or where?